# How to use Key Bindings instead of Key Listeners

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings, keyevent, key-events

I'm using [`KeyListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyListener.html)s in my code (game or otherwise) as the way for my on-screen objects to react to user key input. Here is my code:

```
public class MyGame extends JFrame {

    static int up = KeyEvent.VK_UP;
    static int right = KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT;
    static int down = KeyEvent.VK_DOWN;
    static int left = KeyEvent.VK_LEFT;
    static int fire = KeyEvent.VK_Q;

    public MyGame() {

//      Do all the layout management and what not...
        JLabel obj1 = new JLabel();
        JLabel obj2 = new JLabel();
        obj1.addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener());
        obj2.addKeyListener(new MyKeyListener());
        add(obj1);
        add(obj2);
//      Do other GUI things...
    }

    static void move(int direction, Object source) {

        // do something
    }

    static void fire(Object source) {

        // do something
    }

    static void rebindKey(int newKey, String oldKey) {

//      Depends on your GUI implementation.
//      Detecting the new key by a KeyListener is the way to go this time.
        if (oldKey.equals("up"))
            up = newKey;
        if (oldKey.equals("down"))
            down = newKey;
//      ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new MyGame();
    }

    private static class MyKeyListener extends KeyAdapter {

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

            Object source = e.getSource();
            int action = e.getExtendedKeyCode();

/* Will not work if you want to allow rebinding keys since case variables must be constants.
            switch (action) {
                case up:
                    move(1, source);
                case right:
                    move(2, source);
                case down:
                    move(3, source);
                case left:
                    move(4, source);
                case fire:
                    fire(source);
                ...
            }
*/
            if (action == up)
                move(1, source);
            else if (action == right)
                move(2, source);
            else if (action == down)
                move(3, source);
            else if (action == left)
                move(4, source);
            else if (action == fire)
                fire(source);
        }
    }
}
```

I have problems with the responsiveness:

- I need to click on the object for it to work.
- The response I get for pressing one of the keys is not how I wanted it to work - too responsive or too unresponsive.

Why does this happen and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

*This answer explains and demonstrates how to use key bindings instead of key listeners for educational purpose. It is not*

- *How to write a game in Java.*
- *How good code writing should look like (e.g. visibility).*
- *The most efficient (performance- or code-wise) way to implement key bindings.*

*It is*

- *What I would post as an answer to anyone who is having trouble with key listeners*.

---

Answer; Read the [Swing tutorial on key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

> **I don't want to read manuals, tell me why I would want to use key bindings instead of the beautiful code I have already!**

Well, the *Swing tutorial* explains that

- Key bindings don't require you to click the component (to give it focus):

  - Removes unexpected behavior from the user's point of view.
  - If you have 2 objects, they can't move simultaneously as only 1 of the objects can have the focus at a given time (even if you bind them to different keys).
- Key bindings are easier to maintain and manipulate:

  - Disabling, rebinding, re-assigning user actions is much easier.
  - The code is easier to read.

> **OK, you convinced me to try it out. How does it work?**

The *[tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html#maps)* has a good section about it. Key bindings involve 2 objects `InputMap` and `ActionMap`. `InputMap` maps a user input to an action name, `ActionMap` maps an action name to an `Action`. When the user presses a key, the input map is searched for the key and finds an action name, then the action map is searched for the action name and executes the action.

> **Looks cumbersome. Why not bind the user input to directly to the action and get rid of the action name? Then you need only one map and not two.**

Good question! You will see that this is one of the things that make key bindings more manageable (disable, rebind etc.).

> **I want you to give me a full working code of this.**

No (the *Swing tutorial* has [working examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html#eg)).

> **<s>You suck!</s> I hate you!**

Here is how to make a single key binding:

```
myComponent.getInputMap().put("userInput", "myAction");
myComponent.getActionMap().put("myAction", action);
```

Note that there are 3 `InputMap`s reacting to different focus states:

```
myComponent.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED);
myComponent.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
myComponent.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
```

- `WHEN_FOCUSED`, which is also the one used when no argument is supplied, is used when the component has focus. This is similar to the key listener case.
- `WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT` is used when a focused component is inside a component which is registered to receive the action. If you have many crew members inside a spaceship and you want the spaceship to continue receiving input while any of the crew members has focus, use this.
- `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW` is used when a component which is registered to receive the action is inside a focused component. If you have many tanks in a focused window and you want all of them to receive input at the same time, use this.

The code presented in the question will look something like this assuming both objects are to be controlled at the same time:

```
public class MyGame extends JFrame {

    private static final int IFW = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
    private static final String MOVE_UP = "move up";
    private static final String MOVE_DOWN = "move down";
    private static final String FIRE = "move fire";

    static JLabel obj1 = new JLabel();
    static JLabel obj2 = new JLabel();

    public MyGame() {

//      Do all the layout management and what not...

        obj1.getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"), MOVE_UP);
        obj1.getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"), MOVE_DOWN);
//      ...
        obj1.getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control CONTROL"), FIRE);
        obj2.getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("W"), MOVE_UP);
        obj2.getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("S"), MOVE_DOWN);
//      ...
        obj2.getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("T"), FIRE);

        obj1.getActionMap().put(MOVE_UP, new MoveAction(1, 1));
        obj1.getActionMap().put(MOVE_DOWN, new MoveAction(2, 1));
//      ...
        obj1.getActionMap().put(FIRE, new FireAction(1));
        obj2.getActionMap().put(MOVE_UP, new MoveAction(1, 2));
        obj2.getActionMap().put(MOVE_DOWN, new MoveAction(2, 2));
//      ...
        obj2.getActionMap().put(FIRE, new FireAction(2));

//      In practice you would probably create your own objects instead of the JLabels.
//      Then you can create a convenience method obj.inputMapPut(String ks, String a)
//      equivalent to obj.getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(ks), a);
//      and something similar for the action map.

        add(obj1);
        add(obj2);
//      Do other GUI things...
    }

    static void rebindKey(KeyEvent ke, String oldKey) {

//      Depends on your GUI implementation.
//      Detecting the new key by a KeyListener is the way to go this time.
        obj1.getInputMap(IFW).remove(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(oldKey));
//      Removing can also be done by assigning the action name "none".
        obj1.getInputMap(IFW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStrokeForEvent(ke),
                 obj1.getInputMap(IFW).get(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(oldKey)));
//      You can drop the remove action if you want a secondary key for the action.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new MyGame();
    }

    private class MoveAction extends AbstractAction {

        int direction;
        int player;

        MoveAction(int direction, int player) {

            this.direction = direction;
            this.player = player;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            // Same as the move method in the question code.
            // Player can be detected by e.getSource() instead and call its own move method.
        }
    }

    private class FireAction extends AbstractAction {

        int player;

        FireAction(int player) {

            this.player = player;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            // Same as the fire method in the question code.
            // Player can be detected by e.getSource() instead, and call its own fire method.
            // If so then remove the constructor.
        }
    }
}
```

You can see that separating the input map from the action map allow reusable code and better control of bindings. In addition, you can also control an Action directly if you need the functionality. For example:

```
FireAction p1Fire = new FireAction(1);
p1Fire.setEnabled(false); // Disable the action (for both players in this case).
```

See the [Action tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more information.

> **I see that you used 1 action, move, for 4 keys (directions) and 1 action, fire, for 1 key. Why not give each key its own action, or give all keys the same action and sort out what to do inside the action (like in the move case)?**

Good point. Technically you can do both, but you have to think what makes sense and what allows for easy management and reusable code. Here I assumed moving is similar for all directions and firing is different, so I chose this approach.

> **I see a lot of `KeyStroke`s used, what are those? Are they like a `KeyEvent`?**

Yes, they have a similar function, but are more appropriate for use here. See their [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html) for info and on how to create them.

---

*Questions? Improvements? Suggestions? Leave a comment.
Have a better answer? Post it.*

Comment: Good explanation of Key Bindings in general. `... code will look something like this assuming both objects are to be controlled at the same time:` - I don't think the code provided here will support movement of two objects at the same time.. A KeyBinding is only invoked for the last key pressed. If you hold two keys down, only the Action for the last key will be invoked. If I'm wrong I would love to see a working example. `Have a better answer?` - Check out the *KeyBoard Animation* example from [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/).

Answer (score 6):

Note: this is *not* an answer, just a comment with too much code :-)

Getting keyStrokes via getKeyStroke(String) is the correct way - but needs careful reading of the api doc:

```
modifiers := shift | control | ctrl | meta | alt | altGraph
typedID := typed <typedKey>
typedKey := string of length 1 giving Unicode character.
pressedReleasedID := (pressed | released) key
key := KeyEvent key code name, i.e. the name following "VK_".
```

The last line should better be **exact name**, that is case matters: for the down key the exact key code name is `VK_DOWN`, so the parameter must be "DOWN" (not "Down" or any other variation of upper/lower case letters)

Not entirely intuitive (read: had to dig a bit myself) is getting a KeyStroke to a modifier key. Even with proper spelling, the following will not work:

```
KeyStroke control = getKeyStroke("CONTROL");
```

Deeper down in the awt event queue, a keyEvent for a single modifier key is created with itself as modifier. To bind to the control key, you need the stroke:

```
KeyStroke control = getKeyStroke("ctrl CONTROL");
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easyway that would not require you to read hundreds of lines of code just learn a few lines long trick.

declare a new JLabel and add it to your JFrame (I didn't test it in other components)

```
private static JLabel listener= new JLabel();
```

The focus needs to stay on this for the keys to work though.

In constructor :

```
add(listener);
```

Use this method:

**OLD METHOD:**

```
 private void setKeyBinding(String keyString, AbstractAction action) {
        listener.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyString), keyString);
        listener.getActionMap().put(keyString, action);
    }
```

KeyString must be written properly. It is not typesafe and you must consult the official [list](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke(java.lang.String)) to learn what is the keyString(it is not an official term) for each button.

**NEW METHOD**

```
private void setKeyBinding(int keyCode, AbstractAction action) {
    int modifier = 0;
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL:
            modifier = InputEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT:
            modifier = InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK;
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_ALT:
            modifier = InputEvent.ALT_DOWN_MASK;
            break;

    }

    listener.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyCode, modifier), keyCode);
    listener.getActionMap().put(keyCode, action);
}
```

In this new method you can simply set it using `KeyEvent.VK_WHATEVER`

**EXAMPLE CALL:**

```
  setKeyBinding(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL, new AbstractAction() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("ctrl pressed");

        }
    });
```

Send an anonymous class (or use subclass) of AbstractAction. Override its  `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` and make it do whatever you want the key to do.

**PROBLEM:**

I couldn't get it running for VK_ALT_GRAPH.

```
 case KeyEvent.VK_ALT_GRAPH:
            modifier = InputEvent.ALT_GRAPH_DOWN_MASK;
            break;
```

does not make it work for me for some reason.

Comment: 1) only works as long as the `JLabel` has the focus (mostly other components will have it); 2) "are on your own" or consult the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke(java.lang.String))

Comment: the op is writing a  game so i don't think it would be possible for the JLabel to lose the focus. But can't they get the focus again with `listener.requestFocus();`

I myself is checking the documentation now and will update my answer soon with

Comment: Please check my answer again and notify me if I have made any mistakes. I don't want to misinform anyone. I have tested it to the best of my abilities and it is working so far.

Comment: (1) It isn't necessarily a game (the questions states "game or otherwise"). (2) There are 2 `JLabel`s, how can they both have the focus? (3) Taking the focus with `requestFocus()` is terrible because then you can't have *anything* else have focus (like a menu). (3) Alt Graph does not exist on all keyboards. (4) I suggest you first test everything and only then post, and not post speculations ("Confirmation required"). If something is not working, search or ask if you don't find an answer instead of posting a question in the answer.

Comment: alt graph exists in my keyboard but does not trigger when pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to get key bindings working.

> (Inside `JFrame` subclass using `extends`, which is called by the constructor)

```
// Create key bindings for controls
private void createKeyBindings(JPanel p) {
    InputMap im = p.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
    ActionMap am = p.getActionMap();
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("W"), MoveAction.Action.MOVE_UP);
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("S"), MoveAction.Action.MOVE_DOWN);
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A"), MoveAction.Action.MOVE_LEFT);
    im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("D"), MoveAction.Action.MOVE_RIGHT);
    am.put(MoveAction.Action.MOVE_UP, new MoveAction(this, MoveAction.Action.MOVE_UP));
    am.put(MoveAction.Action.MOVE_DOWN, new MoveAction(this, MoveAction.Action.MOVE_DOWN));
    am.put(MoveAction.Action.MOVE_LEFT, new MoveAction(this, MoveAction.Action.MOVE_LEFT));
    am.put(MoveAction.Action.MOVE_RIGHT, new MoveAction(this, MoveAction.Action.MOVE_RIGHT));
}
```

> Separate class to handle those key bindings created above (where `Window` is the class that `extends` from `JFrame`)

```
// Handles the key bindings
class MoveAction extends AbstractAction {

    enum Action {
        MOVE_UP, MOVE_DOWN, MOVE_LEFT, MOVE_RIGHT;
    }


    private static final long serialVersionUID = /* Some ID */;

    Window window;
    Action action;

    public MoveAction(Window window, Action action) {
        this.window = window;
        this.action = action;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        switch (action) {
        case MOVE_UP:
            /* ... */
            break;
        case MOVE_DOWN:
            /* ... */
            break;
        case MOVE_LEFT:
            /* ... */
            break;
        case MOVE_RIGHT:
            /* ... */
            break;
        }
    }
}
```