# What mistake am I making in adding my key listener?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent, keylistener

My launcher object (represented by a bald eagle picture) for a game I'm making doesn't respond to key events. I know it's an issue with how I'm declaring the listener, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here's my code:

```
public class Main {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    GameTest t = new GameTest();
}

public static class GameTest extends JFrame {

    private static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 800;
    private static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500;
    private GamePanel gamePanel;
    private GameTest gameTest;

    public GameTest() throws IOException {
        super("Deep Fried Freedom");
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        gamePanel = new GamePanel();
        add(gamePanel);
        center(this);
        setVisible(true);
        this.addKeyListener(new aKeyListener());
        this.setFocusable(true);
    }

    public void center(JFrame frame) {
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        Point center = ge.getCenterPoint();

        int w = frame.getWidth();
        int h = frame.getHeight();

        int x = center.x - w / 2, y = center.y - h / 2;
        frame.setBounds(x, y, w, h);
        frame.validate();
    }//end of center method  

    public class aKeyListener implements KeyListener {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        }//end empty keyTyped method

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            Launcher.lRun -= 5;
            gamePanel.move();
        }//end keyPressed method

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        }//end empty keyReleased method

    }//end aKeyListener class

}//end GameTest class
}// end main class


public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
Launcher launcher1;
Background bground1;

public GamePanel() throws IOException {
    super();
    launcher1 = new Launcher();
    bground1 = new Background();
}//end constructor

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(bground1.background, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
    g.drawImage(launcher1.baldEagleImage, 350, 415, null);//paint the launcher
}//end paintComponent method

public void move() {
    launcher1.moveX();
    repaint();
}//end move method
}//end GamePanel class



public class Launcher {

public static int lxCoord;        //the launcher's x coordinate
public static final int lyCoord = 415;
public static int lRun = 0;           //the launcher's x change
public static BufferedImage baldEagleImage;

//Constructor
public Launcher() throws IOException {
    lxCoord = 350;
    baldEagleImage = ImageIO.read(new File("baldeagleimage.jpg"));
}

/**
 * The movement of the launcher in the x direction
 */
public void moveX() {
    lxCoord += lRun;
}//end moveX method


}//end Launcher class


public class Background extends JPanel {

BufferedImage background; 

public Background() throws IOException {
    background = ImageIO.read(new File("flagbackground.jpg"));
}//end constructor
}//end Background class
```

Comment: I did a quick skim - but it doesn't look like you're using `setKeyListener()` or whatever the requisite function is.

Comment: The **real** solution is [not to use `KeyListener` at all - use key binding instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741215/how-to-use-key-bindings-instead-of-key-listeners).

Answer (score 1):

You created a KeyListener but never added it to anything. Also, your KeyListener probably doesn't need to be a JFrame and you may have focus issues so I would recommend switching over to [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for a game.

Answer (score 1):

```
addKeyListener( new aKeyListener() );
```

in the `JFrame` constructor should do it. You should not extend your `aKeyListener` with `JFrame`.

Also, consider using an inner class for your KeyListener, as it will probably not be needed for other classes.

Comment: I appreciate the response. I'm still not getting any response, so I guess I messed up implementing your suggestions. I updated my code, is there any chance you could look back over it and guide me to where I'm going wrong? I don't want the solution, just a helping hand. I'm new to OOP, and programming in general.

Comment: @Ben - I tested your code, and your implementation of the KeyListener is fine (although I recommend to extend `KeyAdapter` instead of implementing `KeyListener` to your inner class to get rid of unused methods, such as keyReleased). 

Try to put a `System.out.print("something");` in your keyPressed and you'll notice that it will type that out whenever your press a button. The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, I realized that my paintComponent method was just repainting the launcher in its initial position every time I called repaint(). I fixed that and now it moves when I hit the "a" button. I appreciate the help!