# Java get key repetition with keyListener

Tags: java, awt, keylistener

I have a small game which uses arrow keys. However if I press the arrow keys within a timeout window of say 200ms, the timeout starting from the first key press, how do I capture all the keys pressed using keyListener?

Comment: this propertry is controled by Native OS, there are repeatly fired pressed and released, solution is usage of KeyBindings (required usage of Swing)

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741215/how-to-use-key-bindings-instead-of-key-listeners) for example. There are other posts about this too.