# thread stops when 2 KeyEvents are pressed

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface

I am writing a snake game in java and the turns are controlled by keyboard. everything works fine, but when i by mistake press 2 keys then the whole application freezes (the gui) snake stops moving, but thread keeps running according to my eclipse, i thought it might be the default case that causes problems, but the statement does not get printed.

```
private class KeyboardListener extends KeyAdapter {

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        Directions direc = c.getDirectionSnake();
        switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
        case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
        case KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD6:
            // if it's not the opposite direction
            if (c.getDirectionSnake() != Directions.LEFT)
                c.setDirectionSnake(Directions.RIGHT);
            break;
        case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
        case KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD8:
            if (c.getDirectionSnake() != Directions.BOTTOM)
                c.setDirectionSnake(Directions.TOP);
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
        case KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD4:
            if (c.getDirectionSnake() != Directions.RIGHT)
                c.setDirectionSnake(Directions.LEFT);
            break;

        case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
        case KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD2:
            if (c.getDirectionSnake() != Directions.TOP)
                c.setDirectionSnake(Directions.BOTTOM);
            break;
        default:
        System.out.println("here");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

jframe

```
public Window() throws FileNotFoundException {

    this.setTitle("Snake");
    this.setSize(400, 450);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    gamePanel = new GamePanel();
    topPanel = new TopPanel();

    this.add(new TopPanel(), BorderLayout.NORTH);

    this.add(gamePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    c = new ThreadsController(gamePanel.getSnakeDepartPosition());
    c.start();
    this.buttonPanel = new ButtonPanel(this, c);
    this.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    this.setVisible(true);

    this.addKeyListener(new KeyboardListener());

}
```

Comment: The error is not in this code...

Comment: Show us where threads get created and where the actual movement happens

Comment: added the jframe code

Comment: Use key bindings instead, for example, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741215/how-to-use-key-bindings-instead-of-key-listeners).

Comment: key binding is a good idea, but it does not solve my problem, tha app will still freeze

Comment: To reply to a user's comment use @username or they will not be notified. As for your problem, the app will not freeze unless you go out of your way to make it so. Follow the steps in the link.