# How to shorten this KeyListener code

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener, performance

I am using this code to detect when the user presses an arrow key in my program. I need which arrow key was pressed to be sent to a method which will process it and do what it needs to do. It's working, but the problem is my code is stupidly long and repetitve, and I'm sure theres a way to shorten this. I can pass integers 0-3 instead of strings if it makes doing this easier. This is my code right now:

```
getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
    KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0), "left"); 
getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
    KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0), "right");
getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
    KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_UP, 0), "up");
getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
    KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, 0), "down");
getRootPane().getActionMap().put("left", new AbstractAction(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        close("left");
    }
});
getRootPane().getActionMap().put("right", new AbstractAction(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        close("right");
    }
});
getRootPane().getActionMap().put("up", new AbstractAction(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        close("up");
    }
});
getRootPane().getActionMap().put("down", new AbstractAction(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        close("down");
    }
});
```

Comment: That's not `KeyListener`, those are key bindings (which are the right way to go). Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741215/how-to-use-key-bindings-instead-of-key-listeners) for an example of encapsulating all movement commands in one action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abstract the common functionality into a method:

```
private void mapKey(String keyStroke, final String command) {
    Action action = new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            close(command);
        }
    };
    getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)
        .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyStroke), action);
    getRootPane().getActionMap()
        .put(action, action);
}
```

And then you can do:

```
mapKey("LEFT",  "left");
mapKey("RIGHT", "right");
mapKey("UP",    "up");
mapKey("DOWN",  "down");
```

Comment: You still need to save the "command" as a variable in the Action as demonstrated by Sergiy.

Comment: +1, I learned something today. An easy way to create variables for an inner class is to make the parameter variable final.

Comment: @camickr Even better, in Java 8, you don't even need to declare them final. They just work!

Comment: I'll try to remember that when I upgrade :)

Answer (score 0):

Create an inner class which extends AbstractAction and can obtain the string parameter

something like this

```
private class CloseAction extends AbstractAction {
    private final String action;
    public CloseAction(String anAction) {
        action = anAction;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        close(action);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
getRootPane().getActionMap().put("up", new CloseAction("up"));
```

Comment: I've added that inner class up at the top of my main class, then replaced that huge block of code with your getRootPane() thing(plus the other 3 directions), but I'm not getting any response for any of the 4 directions.