# Keylistener and timer does not work together

Tags: java, swing, timer, keylistener

For some reason my timer which is for the the enemy does not work with the hero (key listener). I tried to remove the just the enemy button from the panel and it worked normally. 
I noticed that nothing works if the hero is in the path of the zombie/enemy. I want them to face each other so i can do a collision.

I was working on it i realized that i have to click on the the hero  and then i can move him around.

I am doing this for a school project.

```
public class game{

static Timer zom;
static int leftright = 0;
static int updown = 3;

static ImageIcon evilcup = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\asher\\Pictures\\zombie-1.jpg");   
static JButton enemy = new JButton (evilcup);

public static JFrame myframe = new JFrame("Asher's Game Database");
public static JPanel mypanel = new JPanel();


/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

int x = 0, y = 0;


myframe.setSize(1900, 600);     
myframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(myframe.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
myframe.setLocationRelativeTo(myframe);       

// all about the panel
mypanel.setBackground(Color.white);  
mypanel.setLayout(null);  


    ImageIcon herocup = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\asher\\Pictures\\soldier1.jpg");
    final  JButton action = new JButton (herocup);

//  REMOVING BACKGROUND FOR ACTION      
    action.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    action.setBorderPainted(false);
    action.setFocusPainted(false);

//  REMOVING BACKGROUND FOR ENEMY       
    enemy.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    enemy.setBorderPainted(false);
    enemy.setFocusPainted(false);


// FIRST  TIMER  FOR THE EVIL ZOMBIE **************************

    final Timer zom = new Timer(5, new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int currentx, currenty, newx,newy;

            leftright = leftright + 1;

            String  evil = "C:\\Users\\asher\\Pictures\\mario" + leftright + ".gif"; //declearing pic and adding numbers so we dont have to repeate 
            ImageIcon evilcup = new ImageIcon(evil);    //create new pic using newpic
            enemy.setIcon(evilcup);

            if (leftright == 3)
                leftright =0;           

        // COORDINATES OF THE EVIL 
            currentx = enemy.getLocation().x;
            currenty = enemy.getLocation().y;
            newx = currentx + 15;
            newy = currenty;

        //  IF THE OBJECT REACHS TEH END OF THE FRAME BLOCK HIS WAY!!!!
            if (newx >1700)
                newx = 1700;

            enemy.setLocation(newx, newy);

        }// end of sub method
    });// for timechange

//SECOND TIMER FOR DELAYING -------------------------------------------     


    final Timer secondtime = new Timer(2500, new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            zom.setDelay(100);      

        }//end of method

    });// ending of the seconding timer
    secondtime.start();  


//THIRD TIMER FOR STOPPING-------------------------------------------


if (secondtime.isRunning()){    
    final Timer thirdtime = new Timer(5000, new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            zom.stop();
            secondtime.stop();

        }//end of method    

    });//end of third timer     
  }




// KEY LISTENER ----------------------------    


    action.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int currentx, currenty, newx,newy;

    // SETTING UP 'C'  FOR NUMBERS IN GETTING CODE FOR THE KEYS
            int c = e.getKeyCode();


            System.out.print (e.getKeyCode());  
            System.out.print (e.getKeyChar()+ " = ");

            if (e.getKeyCode()==38)
                zom.start();


            //end of if for keycode 38
//  _____________________________________________________________       

            if (e.getKeyCode()==37)
                // GO LEFT *********************
            {
                leftright = leftright -1;

                String  heromove = "C:\\Users\\asher\\Pictures\\mario" + leftright + ".gif"; //declearing pic and adding numbers so we dont have to repeate 
                ImageIcon cup5 = new ImageIcon(heromove);   //create new pic using newpic
                action.setIcon(cup5);

                if (leftright == -3)
                    leftright =0;

                currentx = action.getLocation().x;
                currenty = action.getLocation().y;

                newx = currentx - 15;
                newy = currenty;

            //  IF THE OBJECT REACHS TEH END OF THE FRAME BLOCK HIS WAY!!!!
                if (newx <0)
                    newx = 0;

            //STEP 3 : set new location
                action.setLocation(newx, newy);

            }//end of if for keycode 37

//  _____________________________________________________________       
            if (e.getKeyCode()==39)
                // GO RIGHT **********************
            {

                leftright = leftright +1;

                String  heromove = "C:\\Users\\asher\\Pictures\\mario" + leftright + ".gif"; //declearing pic and adding numbers so we dont have to repeate 
                ImageIcon cup5 = new ImageIcon(heromove);   //create new pic using newpic
                action.setIcon(cup5);

                if (leftright == 3)
                    leftright =0;

                  currentx = action.getLocation().x;
                  currenty = action.getLocation().y;

                  newy = currenty;
                  newx = currentx + 15;

                //  IF THE OBJECT REACHS TEH END OF THE FRAME BLOCK HIS WAY!!!!                     
                  if (newx >1700)
                      newx = 1700;          

                action.setLocation(newx, newy);


            }//end of if for keycode 38
//  _____________________________________________________________           


        }//end of the listener

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent d) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

    });//end of the keylistener




// setting up components and bounds 

     myframe.add(mypanel);
     mypanel.add(action);
     mypanel.add(enemy);

     action.setBounds(1600,200, 100, 200); 
     enemy.setBounds(40,200, 150, 250);

    myframe.setVisible(true);


}//end of method
```

}//end of class

Comment: A `KeyListener` only works if the `Component` has focus....so does `action` have focus? Consider using [KeyBindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to get around this behavior

Comment: @copeg i was working on it i realized that i have to click on the the hero  and then i can move him around.

Comment: that's a focus issue. Call `requestFocus` on the `Component` with the `KeyListener`, or use `KeyBindings`

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741215/how-to-use-key-bindings-instead-of-key-listeners/).