# How to handle keyListener for a pong app in Java used to move the paddle back and forth using the arrow keys

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

```
public class LobPong extends JPanel implements KeyListener, ActionListener {
public static double xCoordinate;
public static double yCoordinate;
public static Timer timer;
static int xPaddleLeft;
private static int yPaddle = 800;
private static int score = 0;
private static int level = 1;
public static JLabel scoreLabel = new JLabel(" Score: 0 "); //instantiation is a debug
public static JLabel timeLabel = new JLabel(" ");
public static JLabel levelLabel = new JLabel(" Level: "); //debug
private static int life;
private static int levelTime = 30000;
public static int dx, dy;
private static double time = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame LobPongApp = new JFrame();
    LobPong canvas = new LobPong();
    canvas.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    LobPongApp.add(canvas);
    LobPongApp.setSize(800, 900);
    LobPongApp.setTitle("Lob Pong");
    LobPongApp.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    LobPongApp.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    LobPongApp.setVisible(true);
    canvas.setFocusable(true);
    LobPongApp.addKeyListener(canvas);

}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.fillOval((int) xCoordinate, (int) yCoordinate, 50, 50);

    g.fillRect(xPaddleLeft, yPaddle, 100, 10);
    drawLife(g, getLife()); 
}


public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
    int key = arg0.getKeyCode();
    System.out.println("testing");
    if(key == 37) {
        if (xPaddleLeft > 0) {
            xPaddleLeft -= 50;
            System.out.println("TEST"); //debug
        }
    }
    if(key == 39) {
        if (xPaddleLeft < (getWidth() - 50)) {
            xPaddleLeft += 50;
        }
    }
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
        dx = 2;
        timer.start();
        timerDisplay.start();
        System.out.println("start"); //debug
    }
    repaint();

}
```

Ok, so I am programming a Lob pong game for a project at school and I am really stuck on the keylistener. I have a friend whose keylistener works exactly like the way mine is programmed, but mine won't seem to budge, the keyPressed method is not even accessed when I run the program. Please help me figure this out!
Thanks!

Comment: You should use Key Bindings: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

Comment: I looked into it, but then this actually works now, but for some reason it only works half the time i run it, i don't change any code, just press run again and sometimes it works, others it doesn't. I thought it could be a problem with me running two timers, but i commented one out to test and it didn't change anything

Comment: Key bindings fix the focus related issues which effect how `KeyListener` works. So if want a solution that "might" work, keep using `KeyListener`, if you want a solution that works, use key bindings

Comment: See [How to use Key Bindings instead of Key Listeners](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741215/how-to-use-key-bindings-instead-of-key-listeners)