# Java slime volleyball image flickering

Tags: java, swing

I have started making slime volleyball. I have run into this problem where the image for the slime character flickers insanely. the image is disappeared just about the same amount of time that it is visible.

I tried removing the super.paint(g); in the paint method and that fixed the problem of flickering, but it created a new problem that wouldn't remove the image from previous locations.

[image: Ball]

Source Code:

```
package slimevolleyball.main;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static int x = 275;
    public static int y = 300;
    public static boolean right = false;
    public static boolean left = false;
    public static boolean jump = false;
    public static int startjump = 0;
    public static int low = 300;
    public static double gravity = 0;
    public static double time = 0;
    public static int startVelocity = 0;
    public static double velocity = 0;

    public static BufferedImage slime1;
    public static BufferedImage slime2;
    public static BufferedImage background;

    static Rectangle FrameSize;

    static JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    public Main() {

        addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

                int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

                switch (keyCode) {

                    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:

                        break;

                    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:

                        break;

                    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:

                        left = false;

                        break;

                    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:

                        right = false;

                }

            }

            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

                int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

                switch (keyCode) {

                    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:

                        if (jump == false) {

                            jump = true;

                            startjump = 1;

                        }

                        break;

                    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:

                        break;

                    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:

                        left = true;

                        right = false;

                        break;

                    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:

                        right = true;

                        left = false;

                        break;

                }

            }

        });

        setFocusable(true);

        setTitle("Slime VolleyBall");

        setSize(600, 400);

        setResizable(true);

        setVisible(true);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        super.paint(g);

        g.drawImage(slime1, x, y, null);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        Main game = new Main();

        slime1 = ImageIO.read(new File("red.png"));

        while (true) {

            MoveSlime1();

            Update();

            game.repaint();

            Thread.sleep(2);

        }

    }

    private static void Update() {

        FrameSize = frame.getBounds();

    }

    private static void MoveSlime1() {

        if (right == true && x <= FrameSize.getWidth() / 2) {

            x += 1;

        } else if (left == true && x >= 0) {

            x -= 1;

        }

        if (jump == true) {

            if (startjump == 1) {

                low = 300;

                gravity = -9.8;

                time = 0;

                startVelocity = 3;

                velocity = 0;

                startjump = 0;

            } else {

                velocity = startVelocity + (gravity * time);

                y -= velocity;

                time += 0.005;

                if (time > 0.01 && y >= low) {

                    jump = false;

                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741215/how-to-use-key-bindings-instead-of-key-listeners.

Answer (score 4):

`JFrame` is not double buffered, hence the flicker, which is just one of a list of reasons why you should not be extending from `JFrame` and overriding it's `paint` method.

Instead, move all your logic over to a class which extends `JPanel` and then override it's `paintComponent` method, this way, you'll get double buffering for free.

Also, you should avoid using `KeyListener`s and favor the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which solves the focus related issues of `KeyListener`

Also, `static` is not your friend, you should learn to live without it