# keylistener not working when active rendering

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I'm attempting to write a very simple platform game in Java. I had parts of it working with passive rendering (with a `Timer` object calling `repaint()` and `revalidate()` etc.) but I've been trying to implement active rendering. It kind of works - in that it renders, and the animation works, but it seems to block the key Listener (which worked fine before) for some reason I don't really understand.

I've recreated the problem as minimally as I can below. When you press a key, there should be terminal output, but there is none. If anyone can tell me why the `keyPressed` etc. methods are not firing, it would be much appreciated.

**Edit** - Modified demo code into one copy/paste as per request

**Edit2** - As suggested by Andrew Thompson, I've removed all the full screen code, and the keylistener still doesn't work

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

class FullScreenRenderWithListener implements KeyListener {

   private JFrame frame;
   private World  world;

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      FullScreenRenderWithListener main = new FullScreenRenderWithListener();
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(main::run);
   }

   private void run()
   {
      initWindow();
      setupWorld();
      frame.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
      frame.pack();
      frame.createBufferStrategy(2);
      frame.setVisible(true);
      world.startActive(frame.getBufferStrategy());
   }

   private void initWindow()
   {
      frame = new JFrame();
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
   }

   private void setupWorld()
   {
      world = new World();
      frame.addKeyListener(this);
      frame.add(world);
      world.addKeyListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event)
   {
      System.out.println("Pressed");
   }

   @Override
   public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event)
   {
      System.out.println("Released");
   }

   @Override
   public void keyTyped(KeyEvent event)
   {
      System.out.println("Typed");
   }
}

class World extends JPanel {

   private static final int FRAMES_PER_SEC = 60;
   private static final int MILL_IN_SEC    = 1000;
   private static final int TICK_LENGTH    =
      MILL_IN_SEC / FRAMES_PER_SEC;
   private BufferStrategy strategy;

   private void sleepUntilEndOfFrame()
   {
      try {
         long used = System.currentTimeMillis() % TICK_LENGTH;
         long left = TICK_LENGTH - used;
         Thread.sleep(left);
      } catch(InterruptedException e) {
         // ... Handle this error
      }
   }

   public void startActive(BufferStrategy strategy)
   {
      this.strategy = strategy;
      setIgnoreRepaint(true);
      while(true) {
         doFrame();
      }
   }

   private void doFrame()
   {
      updateGameState();
      activeRenderFrame();
   }

   private void updateGameState()
   {
      // ..
   }

   private void activeRenderFrame()
   {
      Graphics2D graphicsContext = (Graphics2D)strategy
         .getDrawGraphics();
      paintComponent(graphicsContext);
      strategy.show();
      Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
      graphicsContext.dispose();
      sleepUntilEndOfFrame();
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize()
   {
      return new Dimension(500, 500);
   }


   // Have overridden this method because the class
   // also implements passive rendering if active is
   // not supported
   @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      // .. drawing code
   }
}
```

Comment: The key listener seems to be added to the frame. When a panel is added to the frame, it entirely covers it  and swallows the key events. But then, I cannot see how the original frame got key events, given it was not focusable. For further help, turn the two code samples into one copy/paste and give the `Main` class a sensible name so I can drop it in my 'junk code' package to test..

Comment: @AndrewThompson Done

Comment: Did you try compiling the single copy/paste? And `Demo`? O_o How about  something more specific that is unlikely to be used by someone else with a problem: e.g. `FullScreenRenderWithKeyListener`?

Comment: @AndrewThompson My bad. Try now.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the original code to run and have decided it is just too irritating when run once, to be bothered running again. See if you can replicate the problem in a non full screen app. that does not constantly bring itself in front of the IDE that could kill it easily. I doubt the actual problem has anything to do with being full screen.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Ok, thanks for your help so far. You were quite right, I've now updated it so that all the full screen stuff is gone and the same problem occurs. For good measure I added the listener to both the frame and the world, and still the listeners don't work. If you fancy giving it another go, I've updated the copy/paste in the post.

Comment: I think you should use `KeyBinding` instead of `KeyListener` as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741215/how-to-use-key-bindings-instead-of-key-listeners

Comment: @STaefi I already tried that, it didnt work

Comment: @BenWainwright: Why? What was the problem?

Comment: It was exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is not to consider using `KeyBinding` strategy instead of `KeyListener` specially when you are working with `JPanel`. You can check this out by commenting the infinite `while` loop (disabling the active rendering).

When you are using `KeyListener`, no `KeyEvent` is fired (or at least we can say our listener doesn't called) either using active rendering process or not.

Using `keyBinding` will fix this problem.

But when you uncomment the infinite `while` loop, problem continues to show up again. So What can solve this problem? A new `Thread` for updating the frame is the key!

Check your program which is boosted by `KeyBinding` and a new `Thread` for updating the frame with active rendering strategy:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class FullScreenRenderWithListener implements Runnable
{

    private JFrame frame;
    private World world;

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        FullScreenRenderWithListener main = new FullScreenRenderWithListener ();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater ( main );
    }

    public void run ()
    {
        initWindow ();
        setupWorld ();
        frame.setIgnoreRepaint ( true );
        frame.pack ();
        frame.createBufferStrategy ( 2 );
        frame.setVisible ( true );
        world.startActive ( frame.getBufferStrategy () );
    }

    private void initWindow ()
    {
        frame = new JFrame ();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation ( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        frame.setLocationByPlatform ( true );
    }

    private void setupWorld ()
    {
        world = new World ();
        frame.add ( world );
        frame.setFocusable ( true );
        world.setFocusable ( true );
    }
}

class World extends JPanel
{

    private static final int FRAMES_PER_SEC = 10;
    private static final int MILL_IN_SEC = 1000;
    private static final int TICK_LENGTH = MILL_IN_SEC / FRAMES_PER_SEC;
    private BufferStrategy strategy;
    //
    private static final String PRESSED = "Pressed";
    private static final String RELEASED = "Released";
    private Map < Direction , Boolean > directionMap = new HashMap < Direction , Boolean > ();

    private void sleepUntilEndOfFrame ()
    {
        try
        {
            long used = System.currentTimeMillis () % TICK_LENGTH;
            long left = TICK_LENGTH - used;
            Thread.sleep ( left );
        }
        catch ( InterruptedException e )
        {
            // ... Handle this error
            e.printStackTrace ();
        }
    }

    private void setBindings() {
          int context = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
          InputMap inputMap = getInputMap(context);
          ActionMap actionMap = getActionMap();

          for (Direction direction : Direction.values()) {
             inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(direction.getKeyCode(), 0, false), direction.getName() + PRESSED);
             inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(direction.getKeyCode(), 0, true), direction.getName() + RELEASED);

             // set corresponding actions for the  key presses and releases above
             actionMap.put(direction.getName() + PRESSED, new ArrowKeyAction(true, direction));
             actionMap.put(direction.getName() + RELEASED, new ArrowKeyAction(false, direction));
          }
    }

    public void startActive ( BufferStrategy strategy )
    {
        for ( Direction direction : Direction.values () )
        {
            directionMap.put ( direction , Boolean.FALSE );
        }
        setBindings ();
        //
        this.strategy = strategy;
        setIgnoreRepaint ( true );
        Thread t = new Thread (){
            @Override
            public void run ()
            {
                while ( true )
                {
                    doFrame ();
                }
            }
        };
        t.start ();
    }

    private void doFrame ()
    {
        updateGameState ();
        activeRenderFrame ();
    }

    private void updateGameState ()
    {
        // ..
    }

    private void activeRenderFrame ()
    {
        Graphics2D graphicsContext = (Graphics2D) strategy.getDrawGraphics ();
        paintComponent ( graphicsContext );
        strategy.show ();
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ().sync ();
        graphicsContext.dispose ();
        sleepUntilEndOfFrame ();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize ()
    {
        return new Dimension ( 500 , 500 );
    }

    // Have overridden this method because the class
    // also implements passive rendering if active is
    // not supported
    @Override
    public void paintComponent ( Graphics g )
    {
        super.paintComponent ( g );
        // .. drawing code
    }

    private class ArrowKeyAction extends AbstractAction
    {
        private Boolean pressed;
        private Direction direction;

        public ArrowKeyAction ( boolean pressed , Direction direction )
        {
            this.pressed = Boolean.valueOf ( pressed );
            this.direction = direction;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed ( ActionEvent arg0 )
        {
            directionMap.put ( direction , pressed );
            System.out.println ("Direction: "+ direction + ", State: " + pressed);
        }
    }
}

enum Direction {
   UP("Up", KeyEvent.VK_UP, new Point(0, -1)),
   DOWN("Down", KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, new Point(0, 1)),
   LEFT("Left", KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, new Point(-1, 0)),
   Right("Right", KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, new Point(1, 0));

   private String name;
   private int keyCode;
   private Point vector;
   private Direction(String name, int keyCode, Point vector) {
      this.name = name;
      this.keyCode = keyCode;
      this.vector = vector;
   }
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }
   public int getKeyCode() {
      return keyCode;
   }
   public Point getVector() {
      return vector;
   }
   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return name;
   }
}
```

This sample only binds some `KeyBinding` for the arrow keys. You can check out other keys as well by changing the `setBindings` method. Also you may want to define more `Event`s and another `enum` for other keys.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! That looks like it might be the guy... I'll try out the solution tomorrow.

Comment: my laptop is broken so I can't work until I go back into uni which will be in an hour or so

Comment: don't worry, I'll remember to tick your answer if it works :)

Comment: such a simple fix. That did the job. Thanks!