# Key bindings don't work, Java SE, Swing

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

I'm trying to add a shortcut to my JButton. I've read [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) tutorial and I also have read this page [How to use Key Bindings instead of Key Listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741215/how-to-use-key-bindings-instead-of-key-listeners) and a loooooooooooooot of other questions about key bindings, but haven't found any answer for me

**What I've tried:**

```
public class Example extends JFrame {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Example example = new Example();
    }

    Example(){
        Action action = new Action() {
            @Override
            public Object getValue(String key) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void putValue(String key, Object value) {

            }

            @Override
            public void setEnabled(boolean b) {

            }

            @Override
            public boolean isEnabled() {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void addPropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {

            }

            @Override
            public void removePropertyChangeListener(PropertyChangeListener listener) {

            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        };

        JButton button = new JButton("Hello World!");
        button.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "doSomething");
        button.getActionMap().put("doSomething", action);
        button.addActionListener(action);

        add(button);
        setVisible(true);
        pack();
    }

}
```

I've also tried to make it like that: `getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, true), "doSmth");`

But nothing seems to be working, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your very first example works for me. What do you mean by "and has `actionPerformed` function"?

Comment: Post a [mcve]. Your problem is not in the code snippets you gave.

Comment: I have edited the question, now it shows `NextCardListener`.
I meant that it should do smth, sorry

Comment: Tip: Add @user1803551 (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. While on the subject, please post the MCVE (before this is closed for lack of one).

Comment: @EthanGills Pro hint: The `isEnabled()` method is not there for shits and giggles. You want to return `true` there, rather than `false`. A much easier way to do this would be to use `AbstractAction` rather than `Action`, since you apparently don't know how those work. Also, please don't swear in sample code.

Comment: BTW - `JButton button = new JButton("Suqa");` should be `JButton button = new JButton(suqaBlyat);`

Comment: @AndrewThompson You'll notice that the button has the action listener explicitly added later. It's perfectly fine to pass in a string to the button for text rather than the action.

Comment: @Ordous I've changed `Action` to `AbstractAction` and it works perfectly! Thank you a lot! I've also removed swears from sample code, I'm sorry.

Comment: Please don't add things like `[SOLVED]` to a title. I have reverted that edit. Accepting an answer is enough indication. If there is no answer to accept, post your own.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel okay, I'm sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Action` has a method called `isEnabled` that you've implemented. The Javadoc on it states:

```
/**
 * Returns the enabled state of the <code>Action</code>. When enabled,
 * any component associated with this object is active and
 * able to fire this object's <code>actionPerformed</code> method.
 *
 * @return true if this <code>Action</code> is enabled
 */
```

Since you return a hardcoded `false`, the `Action` is never enabled and the `actionPerformed` method is never called. Your problem is not the binding, it's the action itself!

A simple fix is to change `isEnabled` to return true, or, even simpler yet, use `AbstractAction` in place of `Action`, and override only `actionPerformed` (`AbstractAction` is kind of the "I don't care about all this stuff, just give me the simplest thing possible with one method to implement!")