# Java delete key compare

Tags: java, compare

Hi I ve got one problem:

I write a little calculator in Java Swing. I ve got buttons bind with KeyBindings
and then in actionPerformed I check which key was pressed, it's something like that:

```
if(event.getActionCommand().equals("\b")) {
}
```

My question is: is there any way to compare delete button, like backspace button is compared above?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `KeyEvent` constants to check whether delete key was pressed, e.g.:

```
if (event.getExtendedKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE) {
    //do something
}
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html)'s javadoc for KeyEvent class.

Comment: Yes I know but there is written that its better to use key bindings so im trying to do this that way

Comment: No, it's not. Using key bindings is not a good practice. Have a look at this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/22741216/1120793