# Use addKeyListener in a class to listen keys from another class?

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I am trying to have a thread to listen to keys - which is a different class to where the `JPanel` is created. Below is the class where the `JPanel` is.

```
public class Game extends JPanel {

public static final int WIDTH = 600,
                        HEIGHT = 650;

private static boolean running;

private BufferedImage image;
private Graphics2D g;   

public String str;
private static Thread MyThread;


public Game() {
    super();
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocus();
}



public void addNotify(){
    super.addNotify();
    MyThread myThread = new MyThread(this);

    if(myThread == null){
        myThread = new Thread(myThread);
        myThread.start();
    }
}


public void run() {
    image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();

    while(running){
        update();
        render();
        draw();
        System.out.println(str);                                    
    }
    stop();
}
private void update(){  }

private synchronized void render(){
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

}

private synchronized void draw(){
    Graphics g2 = this.getGraphics();
    g2.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    g2.dispose();
}
public void start(){
    if(running) return;
    running = true;
    run();
}

private void stop() {
    if(!running) return;
    running = false;

    try{
        myThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

**Below is the code where the thread that listens to the `Game` class:**

```
public class MyThread  implements Runnable, KeyListener{

private static Game game;
private static boolean left, right;

public MyThread(Game game) {
    this.game = game;       
}

@Override
public void run() {
    game.addKeyListener(this);
    if(left){game.str = "left";}
    if(right){game.str = "right";}
}


@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){left = true;}
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){right = true;}
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){left = false;}
    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT){right = false;}
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}
}
```

Currently when I run the code, it only prints out `null` even when I try to click left and right arrow keys. I tried inserting `game.str = "string";` in the `run()` method and the console prints out `string`, so the thread works. I think the problem is that `MyThread` is not listening to the `JPanel`. Can you please tell me how do I fix this -- having a separate thread to listen to the `Game` class?

PS. `game.addKeyListener(this)` is in the `run()` method of the `MyThread` class.

Comment: I would highly recommend that you consider using the Key Bindings API over `KeyListener`, it solves a number of issues associated with the `KeyListener` API - see [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

Comment: Your `KeyListener` needs to update some state associated with the `Game` class, rather then updating itself

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Key Bindings instead of Key Listeners](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741215/how-to-use-key-bindings-instead-of-key-listeners)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some way to model the user input, personally, I'd start with a simple `enum`...

```
public enum Input {
    LEFT, RIGHT;
}
```

Next, we need some way to notify interested parties that some kind of input event has occurred...

```
public interface InputHandler {
    public void add(Input input);
    public void remove(Input input);
}
```

Next, your key listener needs some way to communicate the events back to the observer...

*Disclaimer: I don't recommend the user of `KeyListener`, see the end for more details*

```
public class KeyHandler extends KeyAdapter {
    
    private InputHandler inputHandler;
    
    public KeyHandler(InputHandler handler) {
        this.inputHandler = handler;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            inputHandler.add(Input.LEFT);
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            inputHandler.add(Input.RIGHT);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            inputHandler.remove(Input.LEFT);
        } else if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
            inputHandler.remove(Input.RIGHT);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, your `Game` needs some way to manage the input events...

```
public class Game extends JPanel implements InputHandler {

    private Set<Input> inputSet = new HashSet<>();
    //...
    public Game() {
        //...
        addKeyListener(new KeyHandler(this));
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void add(Input input) {
        inputSet.add(input);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void remove(Input input) {
        inputSet.remove(input);
    }
```

All of this means that when some input event occurs, your `Game` is notified, it can update the current state model based on the event.  The `Game` doesn't care that you've used a `KeyListener`, or `JButton` or some other input method, de-coupling it and making it more flexible.

Okay, you say, but how do I check which is pressed?

```
inputSet.contains(Input.LEFT)
```

will return `true` when `LEFT` was pressed and `false` when it is released.

## Observations

Based on what I can deduce from your code, this...

```
public void run() {
    image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    g = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();

    while(running){
        update();
        render();
        draw();
        System.out.println(str);                                    
    }
    stop();
}
```

will never be called.  You're executing a `Thread` using the `KeyListener`, whose run method just adds itself to the panel and the exits.

As you're using Swing, I would strongly recommend using a Swing `Timer` instead, it reduces the risk of race conditions between the painting thread and the update thread, as the `Timer` is triggered with the context of the EDT, making it safer to update the state of the UI from within

## Recommendations

Now, having said all that, I **highly** recommend you **don't** use `KeyListener`, as it suffers from focus related issues, is difficult to maintain, provide customisation and inject other input methods should you want to.

Instead, I'd suggest using the [Key Bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) instead, which will solve these short comming and provide a more robust and re-usable solution

The above solution will still work with key bindings

Comment: Why would you bother? The key event is still going to be dispatched in the context of the EDT. Instead, your observer/update loop should running in its own thread