# JAVA Read Simple Key Press?

Tags: java, swing, if-statement

I want to read a simple a key - how can I add this? Please can anyone help?

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    SetUp_JFrame SetUp_JFrame =new SetUp_JFrame();
    SetUp_JFrame.PART1(); 

    READ_KEY READ_KEY =new READ_KEY();
    for(;;) { 
       READ_KEY.PART2();  
            }
             }}



 class SetUp_JFrame {
     public JFrame f; 
  void PART1()throws IOException {

    f = new JFrame();
    f.setTitle("Test");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(128,128);
    f.setVisible(true);
           }}

class READ_KEY {
  void PART2() {

    A = KeyPress
       System.out.println("You Pressed Key "+A);
    }
     }
```

stackoverflow asking for more detail not sure what more I can say? in Basic you would use something like

```
DO                                 
A=Inkey$                                         
Print A                                                       
Loop
```

Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: Learn basic Java coding conventions. 1) Don't use "_" in class or method names. Have you ever seen this in the Java API? 2) Don't use all upper case characters in class and method names. Again, have you ever seen this in the API? Learn by example and don't make up your own conventions.

Comment: You should start by reading some basic tutorials - [How to Use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) and [How to write a key listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) - there are numrous exampels around - also, you won't need the loop

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to add a [KeyListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) to your `JFrame`.

```
f.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Pressed =" + e.getKeyChar());
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }
});
```

The more preferred way is to use [Key Bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741215/how-to-use-key-bindings-instead-of-key-listeners)

Comment: Thank you for your reply and sorry for the simple questions but I cant figure out how to add this to my current code? Thanks in in advance.

Comment: `f` is your JFrame.  Just add it to your SetUp_JFrame class.  (P.S.  You should never use underscores in class names.)  And remove your READ_KEY class.

Comment: Does anyone know how to add this to it's own class?