# ActionListener or Action for playerMovement

Tags: java, swing, oop, action, keylistener

I am just trying to program a little football game and after doing all the painting and initializing the players and the ball I am now at the point where I try to move the player. I watched some tutorial how to program movement in games but they all using KeyListeners. As I wrote online KeyListener is not a good approach. (Is there still any case to use KeyListeners?). However, I am trying to implement a smooth and for OO manners correct movement. I couldnt find online resources which teach that in the "correct" way. I specify the "correct" way because of suggestions I have read from top Java programmer on SO. I am struggling with **WHAT** to use for movement and **WHERE** to implement it? I thought about using Actions and implement it in an inner class of Player maybe? Is this the right approach?

Here is my code until now:

Speedball:

```
package SpeedballMinimal;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Speedball{

    public static final int AREA_WIDTH = 1400;
    public static final int AREA_HEIGHT = 700;

    public Speedball() {
    }

    private void start() {
        JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame("Speedball");
        SpeedballPanel panel = new SpeedballPanel();
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainFrame.setSize(AREA_WIDTH, AREA_HEIGHT);
        mainFrame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Speedball speedball = new Speedball();
        speedball.start();
    }
}
```

SpeedballPanel:

```
package SpeedballMinimal;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class SpeedballPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private Timer timer;
    private Renderer renderer;
    private Player player1;
    private Player player2;

    public SpeedballPanel() {
        initPanel();
        initUserInteractions();
        initTimer();

        this.renderer = new Renderer();
        this.player1 = new Player(300, 300);
        this.player2 = new Player(500, 500);
    }

    private void initPanel() {
        this.setSize(Speedball.AREA_WIDTH, Speedball.AREA_HEIGHT);
    }


    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        renderer.drawBackground(g, getWidth(), getHeight());
        renderer.drawPlayer(g, player1.getX(), player1.getY(), player1.getWidth(), player1.getHeight());
        renderer.drawPlayer(g, player2.getX(), player2.getY(), player2.getWidth(), player2.getHeight());
    }

    /*
     * Playermovement
     */
    private void playerMoveUp(Player player) {
        player.setY(player.getY() - 10);
        System.out.println("Player Y: " + player.getY());
    }

    private void playerMoveDown(Player player) {
        player.setY(player.getY() + 10);
        System.out.println("Player Y: " + player.getY());
    }

    private void playerMoveLeft(Player player) {
        player.setX(player.getX() - 10);
        System.out.println("Player X: " + player.getX());
    }

    private void playerMoveRigth(Player player) {
        player.setX(player.getX() + 10);
        System.out.println("Player X: " + player.getX());
    }

    /*
     * Actions for playermovement
     */
    Action player1MoveUp = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            playerMoveUp(player1);
        }
    };

    Action player1MoveDown = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            playerMoveDown(player1);
        }
    };

    Action player1MoveLeft = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            playerMoveLeft(player1);
        }
    };

    Action player1MoveRight = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            playerMoveRigth(player1);
        }
    };

    Action player2MoveUp = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            playerMoveUp(player2);
        }
    };

    Action player2MoveDown = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            playerMoveDown(player2);
        }
    };

    Action player2MoveLeft = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            playerMoveLeft(player2);
        }
    };

    Action player2MoveRight = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            playerMoveRigth(player2);
        }
    };

    /*
     * Define keys for user interaction
     */
    private void initUserInteractions() {
        //define InputMaps
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("W"), "player1MoveUp");
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("S"), "player1MoveDown");
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A"), "player1MoveLeft");
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("D"), "player1MoveRight");

        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"), "player2MoveUp");
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"), "player2MoveDown");
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"), "player2MoveLeft");
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "player2MoveRight");

        //define ActionMaps
        this.getActionMap().put("player1MoveUp", player1MoveUp);
        this.getActionMap().put("player1MoveDown", player1MoveDown);
        this.getActionMap().put("player1MoveLeft", player1MoveLeft);
        this.getActionMap().put("player1MoveRight", player1MoveRight);

        this.getActionMap().put("player2MoveUp", player2MoveUp);
        this.getActionMap().put("player2MoveDown", player2MoveDown);
        this.getActionMap().put("player2MoveLeft", player2MoveLeft);
        this.getActionMap().put("player2MoveRight", player2MoveRight);
    }

    private void initTimer() {
        timer = new Timer(1, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Renderer:

```
package SpeedballMinimal;

import java.awt.*;

public class Renderer {

    public Renderer() {
    }

    public void drawBackground(Graphics g, int areaWidth, int areaHeight) {
        g.setColor(new Color(106, 237, 49));
        g.fillRect(0,0, areaWidth, areaHeight);
    }

    public void drawPlayer(Graphics g, int playerX, int playerY, int playerWidth, int playerHeight) {
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(playerX, playerY, playerWidth, playerHeight);
    }
}
```

Player:

```
package SpeedballMinimal;

import java.util.Random;

public class Player {

    private int x;
    private int y;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int velocity = 2;

    private Random rand = new Random();

    public Player() {
        this.x = 300;
        this.y = 300;
        this.width = 50;
        this.height = 50;
    }

   public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(int x) {
    this.y = y;
}

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I edited my Code to a minimal example. This code produces an oval on my JPanel. I tried to create movement for that oval with KeyBindings as suggested. I used this resources:

- [How to use Key Bindings instead of Key Listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741215/how-to-use-key-bindings-instead-of-key-listeners)
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html

**I now want to fix the following problem:**

- I cant move both player at the same time and I couldnt find anything online how to fix this. When player1 is moving and I press the up key for player2, player1 stop moving. Now I want to know, how I can let both player move at the same time

**EDIT 2:**

Here is my new Code based on the answer of c0der

SpeedballPanel (class got changed):

```
package SpeedballMinimal;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SpeedballPanel extends JPanel {

    private Renderer renderer;
    private Player player1;
    private Player player2;

    public SpeedballPanel() {
        initPanel();
        initUserInteractions();

        this.renderer = new Renderer();
        this.player1 = new Player(Team.ONE);
        this.player2 = new Player(Team.TWO);
    }

    private void initPanel() {
        this.setSize(Speedball.AREA_WIDTH, Speedball.AREA_HEIGHT);
    }


    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        renderer.drawBackground(g, getWidth(), getHeight());
        renderer.drawField(g, getWidth(), getHeight());
        renderer.drawGoals(g, getWidth(), getHeight());
        renderer.drawPlayer(g, player1.getX(), player1.getY(), player1.getWidth(), player1.getHeight());
        renderer.drawPlayer(g, player2.getX(), player2.getY(), player2.getWidth(), player2.getHeight());
    }

    /*
     * Playermovement
     */
    private void movePlayer(Player player, MovementDirection direction) {
        if (direction == MovementDirection.UP) {
            player.setY(player.getY() - 10);
        }
        if (direction == MovementDirection.DOWN) {
            player.setY(player.getY() + 10);
        }
        if (direction == MovementDirection.LEFT) {
            player.setX(player.getX() - 10);
        }
        if (direction == MovementDirection.RIGHT) {
            player.setX(player.getX() + 10);
        }
        repaint();
    }

    /*
     * Actions for playermovement
     */
    Action player1MoveUp = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            movePlayer(player1, MovementDirection.UP);
        }
    };

    Action player1MoveDown = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            movePlayer(player1, MovementDirection.DOWN);
        }
    };

    Action player1MoveLeft = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            movePlayer(player1, MovementDirection.LEFT);
        }
    };

    Action player1MoveRight = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            movePlayer(player1, MovementDirection.RIGHT);
        }
    };

    Action player2MoveUp = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            movePlayer(player2, MovementDirection.UP);
        }
    };

    Action player2MoveDown = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            movePlayer(player2, MovementDirection.DOWN);
        }
    };

    Action player2MoveLeft = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            movePlayer(player2, MovementDirection.LEFT);
        }
    };

    Action player2MoveRight = new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            movePlayer(player2, MovementDirection.RIGHT);
        }
    };

    /*
     * Define keys for user interaction
     */
    private void initUserInteractions() {
        //define InputMaps
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("W"), "player1MoveUp");
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("S"), "player1MoveDown");
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A"), "player1MoveLeft");
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("D"), "player1MoveRight");

        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("UP"), "player2MoveUp");
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("DOWN"), "player2MoveDown");
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"), "player2MoveLeft");
        this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "player2MoveRight");

        //define ActionMaps
        this.getActionMap().put("player1MoveUp", player1MoveUp);
        this.getActionMap().put("player1MoveDown", player1MoveDown);
        this.getActionMap().put("player1MoveLeft", player1MoveLeft);
        this.getActionMap().put("player1MoveRight", player1MoveRight);

        this.getActionMap().put("player2MoveUp", player2MoveUp);
        this.getActionMap().put("player2MoveDown", player2MoveDown);
        this.getActionMap().put("player2MoveLeft", player2MoveLeft);
        this.getActionMap().put("player2MoveRight", player2MoveRight);
    }
}
```

MovementDirection (enum got created):

```
package SpeedballMinimal;

public enum MovementDirection {
    UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT
}
```

Note: Remaining classes got not changed

Actually I dont want to move player2 random or automatically, I want it to move by arrow keys as seen in my definition of the InputMaps. But I still have the same problem, when I try to move player1 with WASD keys and try to move player2 at the same time with UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT - arrow keys, that the first moving player stops to move and the other player starts to move, but they are not able to move at the same time. Sorry if I was unclear in my first post about the movement of the player.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than the lower level `KeyListener`. 3) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.

Comment: TL; DR; please post [mcve] as suggested

Comment: @AndrewThompson I have edit my question, and about naming conventions: I did everything as you mentioned, but already before? Couldnt find anything wrong.

Comment: @c0der I have edit my question

Comment: I see here 3 questions : "Is it a good idea to implements ActionListener" (not sure why you want to do it) , "where should I implement it" , and "I cant move both player at the same time" . SO post are meant for one question with clear concise problem statements. Please make it clear which one you want an answer for.

Comment: @c0der you are right, I am sorry. I edited my question and just want to know, how I can let both player move at the same time

Comment: As for the structure I recommend reading about [MVC Pattern](http://www.javafaq.nu/java-article714.html), and it [PMVC](http://aalmiray.github.io/griffon-patterns/#_pmvc) variation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code one can assume that you want the other ball be moved by the timer.
Apply changes as per the following code to move player 1 (key actions are moving palyer 2, although you wanted it to move player 1. I did not check why).

```
private void initTimer() {
    timer = new Timer(500, this);
    timer.start();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //move player 1
    randomMovePlayer(player1);
    repaint();
}

//randomly move player
private void randomMovePlayer(Player player) {

    Random rand = new Random(); //refactor it to a field
    float direction = rand.nextFloat();
    if(direction < .25) {
        playerMoveLeft(player);
    }else if(direction < .5) {
        playerMoveUp(player);
    }else if(direction < .75) {
        playerMoveDown(player);
    }else  {
        playerMoveRigth(player1);
    }
    //todo improve logic to get the right movement within bounds
}
```

Also at each of the four move methods you need to repaint after the move :

```
private void playerMoveUp(Player player) {
    player.setY(player.getY() - 10);
    System.out.println("Player Y: " + player.getY());
    repaint(); //repaint after each move
}
```

Side note: all four moves could be handled by one method:

```
enum Direction{LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN};

private void movePalyer(Player player, Direction dir) {
    //todo move logic 
}
```

In response to Edit 2: 
Try to start a continuous movement when key is pressed (by starting a timer), and stop it when the same key is released.

```
//do on w key press
this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W,0, false), "player1MoveUp");
//do on w key release
this.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W,0, true), "stop");

Action player1MoveUp = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        move(new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                movePlayer(player1, MovementDirection.UP);
            }
        });
    }
};

//note that you can't use the same timer for both
//players if you don't want a button release stop both
private void move(Action play) {
    if((timer !=null) && timer.isRunning()) { //timer is a field 
        return;
    }
    timer = new Timer(100, play);
    timer.setInitialDelay(0);
    timer.start();
}

Action stop = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        timer.stop();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help,  I thought about using something like an enum, just needed a little hint. Although thats not fixing my problem. See Edit 2 pls in my question