# Code completion not working for RSyntaxTextArea

Tags: java, swing, rsyntaxtextarea

I got `RSyntaxTextArea` working in JavaFX using a SwingNode, but can't seem to get code completion to work. So to remove any JavaFX related problems I implemented a Java/Swing only version with no JavaFX whatsoever. Here's that code:

```
package com.mystuff.swingtest;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import org.fife.ui.autocomplete.*;
import org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.RSyntaxTextArea;
import org.fife.ui.rsyntaxtextarea.SyntaxConstants;
import org.fife.ui.rtextarea.RTextScrollPane;

class AutoCompleteDemo extends JFrame {

    public AutoCompleteDemo() {

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        RSyntaxTextArea textArea = new RSyntaxTextArea(20, 60);
        textArea.setSyntaxEditingStyle(SyntaxConstants.SYNTAX_STYLE_JAVA);
        textArea.setCodeFoldingEnabled(true);
        contentPane.add(new RTextScrollPane(textArea));
        
        CompletionProvider provider = createCompletionProvider();

        AutoCompletion ac = new AutoCompletion(provider);
        ac.install(textArea);

        setContentPane(contentPane);
        setTitle("AutoComplete Demo");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    /**
     * Create a simple provider that adds some Java-related completions.
     */
    private CompletionProvider createCompletionProvider() {

        DefaultCompletionProvider provider = new DefaultCompletionProvider();

        // Add completions for all Java keywords. A BasicCompletion is just
        // a straightforward word completion.
        provider.addCompletion(new BasicCompletion(provider, "abstract"));
        provider.addCompletion(new BasicCompletion(provider, "assert"));
        provider.addCompletion(new BasicCompletion(provider, "break"));
        provider.addCompletion(new BasicCompletion(provider, "case"));
        // ... etc ...
        provider.addCompletion(new BasicCompletion(provider, "transient"));
        provider.addCompletion(new BasicCompletion(provider, "try"));
        provider.addCompletion(new BasicCompletion(provider, "void"));
        provider.addCompletion(new BasicCompletion(provider, "volatile"));
        provider.addCompletion(new BasicCompletion(provider, "while"));

        // Add a couple of "shorthand" completions. These completions don't
        // require the input text to be the same thing as the replacement text.
        provider.addCompletion(new ShorthandCompletion(provider, "sysout",
                "System.out.println(", "System.out.println("));
        provider.addCompletion(new ShorthandCompletion(provider, "syserr",
                "System.err.println(", "System.err.println("));

        return provider;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Instantiate GUI on the EDT.
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                String laf = UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName();
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(laf);
            } catch (Exception e) { /* Never happens */ }
            new AutoCompleteDemo().setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

But when I type `sysout` and hit `crtl+SPACE` nothing happens. No popup window or anything. I checked the keystroke combination from the AutoComplete object and it says "ctrl pressed SPACE" so I know the key combination is correct.

I'm using a Mac. Tried COMMAND, ALT instead of Control, but still nothing. Any ideas?

**UPDATE 1**

If I press `SPACE` and hold down `ctrl` in that order, the pop up flashes on and off and when I release `ctrl` the pop up stays on if I catch it correctly

**UPDATE 2**

This led me to try changing the Trigger Key. I've not worked out the `ctrl-whatever` combination yet, but I tried

```
ac.setTriggerKey(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('\t'));
```

and pressing `TAB` in the editor now brings up the pop-up window without the flashing. So I'll probably be able to fix the original problem if I can just find the right key combination for `KeyStroke`.

Comment: When you say code completion is not working, do you mean in the editor for your Java code or in your own program?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2.3 Community Edition to write the above Java program

Comment: Thanks, that answers my first question that I deleted. Please refresh the page to see my second question.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice IntelliJ is working fine. It's my program that's not showing the pop-up when I press `ctrl+SPACE`. But If I press `SPACE` and hold down `ctrl` the pop up flashes on/off. If I release `ctrl` then the pop up stays on if I catch it in the on state.

Comment: The correct TriggerKey combination is turning out to be problematic for `control + space`... nothing seems to work so far.

Comment: I wonder if something else is intercepting `CTRL+Space`. Maybe there is an OS level keybinding?

Answer (score 1):

By adding a key listener it's possible to reverse engineer the Key Stroke string:

```
        textArea.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e) {
            }
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e) {}
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent e) {
                System.out.println(KeyStroke.getKeyStrokeForEvent(e).toString());
            }
        });
```

Unfortunately `ctrl+SPACE` produces just `released CONTROL` which makes no mention of the space character. However `ctrl+ENTER` produces `ctrl released ENTER` which works a charm and is an acceptable alternative.

Still doesn't solve the `ctrl+SPACE` problem though !

**UPDATE 2**

I [worked out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741215/how-to-use-key-bindings-instead-of-key-listeners) how to get control key working, but still no space key yet:

```
      ac.setTriggerKey(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl CONTROL"));
```

I will update later if I figure out how to get `ctrl+space` working.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

It's not exactly a solution, but it's a work around for now.

```
        ac.setTriggerKey(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('^'));
```

so currently I have to press `SHIFT+6` to get the pop up, which works, where I know I won't be using the `^` character in code.